# Limiting input symbols in text input in drupal 6

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-6

I have input text area, and i need to limit imput symbols to only digits, +/-/" ". Is there any way to do that without making own JS file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML, you can set `<input pattern="[0-9+\- ]*">`. Browser support to this HTML5 feature is limited, and author’s control over error reporting and handling are primitive.

Normally people do this kind of browser-side checks with JavaScript. It does not require a JavaScript file; the code can be embedded in an HTML document.

Comment: I would try this way, but i found, that i cant edit html at all, so decided to use JS.